# Form input size

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

How do I change the input box so it makes a new line after a certain length and also so that it adjusts its size too  in react js

```
<form> 
                                        <input
                                         className="form message"
                                         onBlur={handleBlur}
                                         placeholder="MESSAGE"
                                         onChange={handleChange}
                                         name="message"
                                         value={values.message}
                                          />
</form>
```

Comment: use CSS to set `width` value , probably propoprtional to the `font-size` value of the same element. Use `rem` or `em`  size units.

Answer (score 1):

For multiline inputs, you should use texteareas. If you want to dynamically change its height, maybe you could just increment the `rows` attribute depending on your content length.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a `<textarea>`. In practice, `<input>` fields should only be one line.

You do not need React to modify the height of a textarea. You can do it pretty easily below:

```js
function updateHeight(element) {
  element.style.height = "1px";
  element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight)+"px";
}
```

```css
textarea{
  width:90%;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<textarea oninput="updateHeight(this)" style="overflow:hidden; height:19px"></textarea>
```

Comment: When I said react Js i was just referring to the JSX language as its not exactly the same as html thank you any way